# Telephone call are not working after upgrading to cordova 3.6

Tags: cordova

After upgrading my project to cordova 3.6, the phone calls tag is not working in Android.

```html
<a class="icons" href="tel:+1-800-555-1234" align="center" > Order Food </a>
```

this is my HTML code and here is my config file.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.foodOrders" version="0.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <name>Food Order</name>        
    <content src="index.html" />        
<feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />  
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

The permission is allowed here and it works fine before updating to cordova 3.6 version. Last tested in cordova version 3.5 and its works fine in it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add  **`<access origin="*" launch-external="yes" />`**  in you config file and it will work.

Apache Corodva has release 3.6 [link here](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/09/22/cordova-361.html) you can find the changes which is adopt in it.
Up to corodva 3.5.0 version you do not need to add explicitly "external" permission for application whitelist in its config file. But this cause of security vulnerable as reported in CB-7291.[see this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7291)

> Any URL not explicitly whitelisted was sent to the Android intent
>   system for handling. This was the cause of the security
>   vulnerabilities reported by IBM and disclosed in CVE-2014-3502